# UTF-8 character in code behind 

Tags: c#, asp.net, utf-8, code-behind

I have a web site and it has some words with Turkish characters (ü,ş,ö,ç). There is no problem while is viewing, but when I want to use the words in the code behind for example CheckBoxList.SelectedItem.Text, they are looking as html codes. 
For example; a labels text value is 'EYLÜL'. but when i looking that label's text value from code behind i'm seeing `EYL&#220;L`.

Code found in web.config file, saved in utf-8 format.

```
<globalization
fileEncoding="utf-8"
requestEncoding="utf-8"
responseEncoding=""
culture="tr-TR"
uiCulture="tr-TR"
/>
```

How can you normally see the charachers in codebehind ?

Thanks for your helps.

KR,

Çağın

Comment: Can you give us the code that you render this text ? (is on checkboxlist ? on text control ? on what ?)

Comment: ((int)Enum.Parse(typeof(EnumAylar), row.Cells[byAyIndex].Text)); row is a gridview row.

Comment: not able to get your question properly. I mean you are getting that text fine, but which code behind are yor talking about?